# File execution flow When customer click on Proceed to checkout

Tags: file, magento

When user complete with shopping and go with "Proceed to Checkout", how magento will execute files/values from backend.

For ex. when user enter "shipping information" and press continue which backend files are used and how values are pass to one file to another.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The values users provide (i.e. addresses, shipping and payment methods) are stored in a quote object, which can be accessed by calling Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote().

If you are using onepage checkout, the forms are submitted to the actions of the Mage_Checkout_OnepageController, such as Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::saveBillingAction, Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::savePaymentAction etc. These functions validate user input and save it into the quote object, which is converted into an order at the end of the process.

Comment: Thanx for reply . I have used one model which get data from Magento getquote. Now I want to change those data values from my model. So at that time from where getQuote is used to change that. what is flow and how to change those data

Comment: You can call Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote() from anywhere in your checkout process, even from your model. Once you get the quote object you can change whatever data you need and save the quote by calling $quote->save(), or better $quote->collectTotals()->save() if you made changes that can affect the quote totals. If you need to access the posted data use Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost($key), where $key is a param name.